# If $A$ is positive definite, when is $BAC$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three real, square matrices $A, B, C$ (not symmetric). I am interested in showing that $$x^\top B^\top ACx > 0, \forall x \neq 0.\tag{1}\label{1}$$ I make the assumption that $$x^\top Ax > 0, \forall x \neq 0,$$ and want to find a condition for $B$ and $C$ such that Eq. \eqref{1} holds. Clearly, $B = C$ is sufficient, but in my case $B$ is an approximation for $C$ so I want a weaker assumption. I have been trying to show that $$x^\top B^\top Cx > 0, \forall x \neq 0\tag{2}\label{2}$$ is sufficient, but I have not been able to prove this or find a counterexample. Is there a known proof or counterexample regarding \eqref{2}, or is there a different similarity condition I could impose on $B$ and $C$ to make \eqref{1} hold?

Comment: If $M=(A+A^T)/2 $ then $M$ is positive definite. Writing $A=M+H$ with $H$ anti symmetric the condition $x^TB^TACx>0$ (for $x\neq 0$) is equivalent $x^TB^TMCx>0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to find counterexamples.  Try $$A = \pmatrix{\epsilon & 0\cr 0 & 1},\ 
B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr},\ C = \pmatrix{1+\epsilon & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$$
where $\epsilon > 0$ is small. We have $x^\top B^\top C x > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$,
but $$ \pmatrix{-2 & 1\cr} B^\top A C \pmatrix{-2\cr 1\cr} = 4 \epsilon^2 +2 \epsilon - 1 < 0 $$
if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.  Add small perturbations if you want to make $A, B, C$ non-symmetric.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot!